# Check whether element's parent has a li tag with php

Tags: php, html-lists, parent, simple-html-dom

Basically, I want to check whether the parent of a link is an `<li>` element.

I'm using the Simple DOM Parser library. I get the links like this ($brokenlink is a URL):

```
$html = file_get_html($file);
$matches = $html->find("a[href=$brokenlink]");
```

I then loop through $matches

```
foreach ($matches as $value) {

}
```

My logic would go:

If the parent of $value is not 'li',
Do:

Thanks

Comment: How does your PHP script know about your element(s)? Are you working with a string of HTML or something?

Comment: thanks for the reply - I just clarified

Comment: What is `file_get_html`?

Comment: @JonathanSampson A method of [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks; I typically use `DOMDocument`, so I'm not all that familiar with similar methods.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just say `$matches = $html->find("li > a[href=$brokenlink]");`?

Comment: @FrancisAvila: he wants to find `a` tags that are NOT children of an `li`

Comment: Ah, that explains it. He did a good job of burying the lead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), you can use `$value->parent()` to get the parent node, and `tag` to get the tag name:

```
$html = file_get_html($file);
$matches = $html->find("a[href=$brokenlink]");
foreach ($matches as $value) {
    $parent = $value->parent();
    if($parent->tag != 'li') {
        //not a child of li, do something...
    }
}
```

You can get more by reading the [manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm), which has everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

It would be trivial to run through a NodeList of anchors using `DOMXPath` and `DOMDocument`:

```php
// Create a new DOMDocument, load up our HTML
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// Create a new DOMXPath object, and get our links
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$links = $xpath->query("//a[not(parent::li)][@href='$brokenURL']");

// Cycle over each anchor, check parentNode's nodeName
foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo "'{$link->nodeValue}' is not the child of a list item.";
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/UCtR49p4

Comment: Might as well just say `$xpath->query("//a[not(parent::li)][@href='$brokenURL']")`

Comment: @FrancisAvila Nice alternative indeed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [simplehtml manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm), the parent of an element is available as `$e->parent()`. So you could do this:

```
$html = file_get_html($file);
$anchors = $html->find("a[href=$brokenlink]");

for ($anchors as $a) {
    if ($a->parent()->tag !== 'li') {
        // do something
    }
}
```